# Upgrade Mac OS X from 10.8.5 to 10.10.5

Tags: macos, mac, software-update, software

How do I upgrade my Mac OS X from 10.8.5 to 10.10.5?

I obviously can't use a 10.9 or a 10.10 Combo Updater.

Comment: Note for future - always download a major OS version, even if you never plan to install it. It populates your purchase list for later.

Answer (score 3):

To upgrade from 10.8.5 to 10.9 or 10.10 you had to "purchase" Mavericks or Yosemite in the Apple App Store previously. Purchase is overstated because it was free then. After launching the final El Capitan 10.11.0 in the public the possibility to get the former systems in the store is gone if they don't populate your purchase list.

The Combo Updaters only update a system to a later or the latest point release:

10.9.1 -> 10.9.5 or
10.0.0 -> 10.10.5

Comment: yes thank you very much for your quick response - 
I know its tricky - but my question is still how can I update from 10.8.5 to 10.10.5

Comment: @CHRIS Ask a friend with a larger purchase list, visit the grey net...

Answer (score -3):

Go to App Store → Updates. Wait a while whilst it checks for updates. If you are eligible you will see the screen below. Click on Free Upgrade to get the upgrade.

[image]

Comment: Does that go from 10.8 to 10.10 or just from 10.11 or 10.12 to the latest 10.12?

Comment: @grgarside Its been a long time my friend :)